# perl database connection using fetchrow command

Tags: perl, database-connection

I am using perl code to connect to database.Is the below a compilation error?

```
my $source_id = $syb_qp->fetchrow();
```

The RHS is returning an array. LHS is a scalar.

Below is the part of it

```
my $syb_query="SELECT ms.source_id
                from message ms,message_ mpt
                where ms.msg=mpt.msg and mpt.pattern='$pattern'
                and ms.id = '$invid'" ;
my $syb_qp = $dbs->prepare($syb_query);
$syb_qp->execute();
my $source_id = $syb_qp->fetchrow();
```

And after that I am inserting in a table the $source_id as-

my $syb_query_insert="INSERT INTO invocati (date,id,source,log_m,log_f) VALUES('date',ABC,**$source_id**,'$pattern','$file')";

will the above code will work fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What module are you using?  I don't know of any `fetchrow()` method.

If using [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI), the documentation for [`fetchrow_array()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_array) states:

> If called in a scalar context for a statement handle that has more than one column, it is undefined whether the driver will return the value of the first column or the last. So don't do that. Also, in a scalar context, an undef is returned if there are no more rows or if an error occurred. That undef can't be distinguished from an undef returned because the first field value was NULL. For these reasons you should exercise some caution if you use fetchrow_array in a scalar context.

Therefore, just make the LHS a list:

```
my ($source_id) = $syb_qp->fetchrow_array();
```

Also, I strongly urge you to never include variables inside your SQL, but instead to use [`Placeholders and Bind Values`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values)

```
my $syb_query= q{SELECT ms.source_id
                from message ms,message_ mpt
                where ms.msg=mpt.msg and mpt.pattern=?
                and ms.id=?};
my $syb_qp = $dbs->prepare($syb_query);
$syb_qp->execute($pattern, $invid) or die $syb_qp->errstr;
```

Comment: select returning single value and afterthat I need to insert that value in table using insert command.  "INSERT INTO invocati (date,id,source,log_m,log_f) VALUES('date',ABC,$source_id,'$pattern','$file')   where $source_is is varchar(20) column,so now can I use scalr on LHS of fetchro function...?